# Simple mod_rewrite not working / removing "www."?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a really simple mod_rewrite rule to work on my website.

So far, my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^http://mywebpage.com/study$ http://mywebpage.com/jobs.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to make `http://mywebpage.com/jobs.html` available at `http://mywebpage.com/study`. I've already made sure that the .htaccess file is not being ignored - everything is alright, if I enter junk into the file, the webpage crashes. So why is this not working?

---

Also, I plan to use the following snippet from the HTML5 Boilerplate:

```
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com".

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

So I guess it would be wise to have that snippet *before* my study rewrite rule? Are there any problems I could get by using the above snippet together with my custom rewrite rules?

Comment: The `HOST` is not available in the rule, so drop the `http://mywebpaghe.com/` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mustn't enter the full url in a `RewriteRule` regex, try this piece of code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule ^study$ jobs.html [L]
</IfModule>
```